# Scala - how to make val visible

Tags: scala, visibility

I have this method

```
def example(something):something {
  val c=List()
  if(){
    if(){
      val a=List()
    }
    else{
      val a=List()
    }
  }
  //here a or b are not declared
  c:::a
}
```

How to declare it and make it visible? **I can not use var**.

Comment: You have no 'else' with the first 'if', so 'a' is not defined for all cases. And i think it's better to split the ifs into several small functions, better for readability and easier to combine.

Comment: *What* do you want to make visible for *whom*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make it visible outside declaration scope, so, maybe, try this:

```
def example(somthing):somthing{    
  val c = { 

    if (something) {
      (0 to 10).toList
    } else {
      (0 to 5).toList
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Almost **Everything** in Scala returns a value (the exception is for statements such as package declarations and imports)

if/else statements, pattern matches, etc. etc.

This means that your if/else block returns a value, and is especially keen to do so, very much like the `?:` ternary operator in Java.

```
val foo = ... some integer ...
val bar = if(foo >= 0) "positive" else "negative"
```

Or using blocks:

```
val foo = ... some integer ...
val bar = if(foo >= 0) {
  "positive"
} else {
  "negative"
}
```

Nest 'em to your heart's content if you wish!

```
val foo2 = ... some other integer ...
val bar = if(foo >= 0) {
  if(foo2 >= 0) {
    "double positive"
  } else {
    "part-way there"
  }
} else {
  "foo was negative"
}
```

and even mix 'n' match styles:

```
println(
  if(foo >= 0) {
    if(foo2 >= 0) "double positive" else "part-way there"
  } else {
    "foo was negative"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, you do not need the `val a`:

```
def example(something):something {
  val c= yourListC ::: if(firstTest){
                         if(secondTest){
                           yourListA
                         }
                         else{
                           yourOtherListA
                         }
                       } else {
                           anAdequateEmptyList
                       }
}
```

Comment: What if firstTest is false? Try it in REPL.

Comment: Yes, I've missed that part in my first version.